# bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

Estou tentando rodar esse código:

```
import time

import urllib.request

from urllib.request import urlopen

ibov = ['BBAS3.SA', 'PETR4.SA']

def yahooKeyStats(stock):

try:
    sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen ('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/.../key-statistics?p=' +stock).read()
    pl = sourceCode.split('Preço/Livro </td><td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
    print ("preço livro:", pl)

except Exception as e:
       print (e)
```

Já verifiquei todas as possibilidades e não consigo corrigir. Desculpem-me a pergunta, que pode ser boba, mas estou iniciando e tenho dúvidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é bem simples. Se você verificar o urlopen retorna um objeto do tipo "bytes" converta "sourceCode" para string primeiro:

```
sourceCode = str(sourceCode)
pl = sourceCode.split('Preço/Livro </td><td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
print ("preço livro:", pl)
```

Outra coisa e o que você está fazendo para extrair o preço das ações é um pouco confuso recomendo você usar o [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) para extrair informaçãoes de um documento HTML.

Comment: obrigado. desculpas por não responder antes.

Comment: @Baco23 se o problema foi resolvido, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta para marcá-la como resolvida.